# Using batchWriteItem in dynamodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have two tables in my dynamo db one is candidate table and the other one is user table I want to use batchWriteItem in dynamo db in order to add the data in the table.

The query which I have formatted is as follows

```
var user = {
        userid: usrid,
        role: 'candidate',
        password: vucrypt.encryptpass(pass)
      };

      var canduser = {
        fname: req.body.fname,
        lname: req.body.lname,
        location: req.body.location,
        phone: req.body.phone,
        ccode: req.body.ccode,
        grad: req.body.grad,
        pgrad: req.body.pgrad,
        ograd: req.body.ograd,
        experience: exp,
        linkedin: req.body.linkedin,
        terms: tandc
      };
      canduser = vutools.fixcanduser(canduser);
      canduser.userid = usrid;

      var writes = {
        'users': [{put: user}],
        'candidate': [{put: canduser}],
      };
```

But if i use
 `dynamodb.batchWriteItem(writes, function(err, regdata) {
 }`

Its ending up as error. 
How can I write the right query? The error I am getting is this.

```
MultipleValidationErrors: There were 3 validation errors:
* MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'RequestItems' in params
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'users' found in params
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'candidate' found in params
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the right answer there are some type problems.

```
  var createuser = {
    "RequestItems": {
      "users": [{
           "PutRequest": {
               Item: {
                    "userid": {
                        "S": usrid +""
                    },
                    "password": {
                        "S": vucrypt.encryptpass(pass) +""
                    },
                    "role": {
                      "S": 'candidate' +""
                    }
                }
             }
        }],
      "candidate": [{
           "PutRequest": {
             Item: {
                  "ccode": {
                      "S": req.body.ccode +""
                  },
                  "fname": {
                      "S": req.body.fname +""
                  },
                  "lname": {
                      "S": req.body.lname +""
                  },
                  "pgrad": {
                      "S": req.body.pgrad +""
                  },
                  "videoresumeurl": {
                      "S": "-"
                  },
                  "phone": {
                      "S": req.body.phone +""
                  },
                  "terms": {
                      "S": tandc +""
                  },
                  "location": {
                      "S": req.body.location +""
                  },
                  "experience": {
                      "N": req.body.experience +""
                  },
                  "userid": {
                      "S": usrid +""
                  },
                  "grad": {
                      "S": req.body.grad +""
                  }
               }
             }
        }]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 13):

To batchwrite in DynamoDB, the data must be formated in the dynamodb way. 
if you want do it in standard json, go for the documentclient.
you have an example below, have in mind that dynamobb batchwrite only accept mawimum of 25 element by request.

so according to the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/dynamodb-example-table-read-write-batch.html) you must have :

**1. Attributes**

> "ATTRIBUTE_1": { "S": "ATTRIBUTE_1_VALUE" }

According to your example :

> "role": {"S":"candidate"}

**2. Items**

Each item must have this format

```
      PutRequest: {
        Item: {
            ...,
            "ATTRIBUTE_1": { "S": "ATTRIBUTE_1_VALUE" },
            ...
        }
      }
```

**3. Array of items to add**

Create an array of items, which doesn't exceed 25 elements, (it's a dynamodb limit for batchwrite)

**4. Your request params**

put it together

```
var params = {
  RequestItems: {
    "TABLE_NAME": [
        //the array you just created in step 3
     ]
   }
}
```

**5. The request**

```
ddb.batchWriteItem(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  } else {
    console.log("Success", data);
  }
});
```

**UPDATE**

Your example will be something like this :

```
var params = {
  "RequestItems": {
    "TABLE_NAME": [
      {
        "PutRequest": {
          Item: {
            "userid": { "N": "usrid" },
            "role": { "S": 'candidate' },
            "password": { "S": vucrypt.encryptpass(pass) }
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "TABLE_NAME2": [
      {
        "PutRequest": {
          Item: {
            "fname": {
              "S": req.body.fname
            },
            "lname": {
              "S": req.body.lname
            },
            "location": {
              "S": req.body.location
            },
            "phone": {
              "S": req.body.phone
            },
            "ccode": {
              "S": req.body.ccode
            },
            "grad": {
              "S": req.body.grad
            },
            "pgrad": {
              "S": req.body.pgrad
            },
            "ograd": {
              "S": req.body.ograd
            },
            "experience": {
              "S": exp
            },
            "linkedin": {
              "S": req.body.linkedin
            },
            "terms": {
              "S": tandc
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: The above query is right (Which I wrote) There is table name and all missing I don't know how to put those in the query above can u help me with that?

Comment: This is somthing which i am looking for https://www.markomedia.com.au/dynamodb-for-javascript-cheatsheet/

Comment: can you show me an example based on the query which i have wrote?

Comment: @ArunVM i added an update, but check the types according to your needs

Comment: Thease are two tables `'users': [{put: user}],
        'candidate': [{put: canduser}],` The answer is only having one table this is where i am getting stuck.

Comment: you can only batchwrite in a single table

Comment: No that is wrong we  can write to more than one table https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html But i am not able to format a query

Comment: yep you are right, my fault, i just edited the code, try it now

Comment: I am getting this bug now `InvalidParameterType: Expected params.RequestItems['candidate'][0].PutRequest.Item['experience'].S to be a string`

Comment: all the values must be string. so just parse everything into string

Comment: I tried but getting this now `ValidationException: A value provided cannot be converted into a number`

Comment: I have added this as a question sepratly luike this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51705330/dynamo-db-type-conversion-error-validationexception-a-value-provided-cannot-be