# Dynamo db type conversion error ValidationException: A value provided cannot be converted into a number

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamo DB query like this. Which I execute to add data to two different table and this question is the continuation of the first question. [Using batchWriteItem in dynamodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51702342/using-batchwriteitem-in-dynamodb/)

```
  var createuser = {
        "RequestItems": {
          "users": [
            {
              "PutRequest": {
                Item: {
                  "userid": { "N": "usrid" },
                  "role": { "S": 'candidate' },
                  "password": { "S": vucrypt.encryptpass(pass) }
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "candidate": [
            {
              "PutRequest": {
                Item: {
                  "fname": {
                    "S": req.body.fname
                  },
                  "lname": {
                    "S": req.body.lname
                  },
                  "location": {
                    "S": req.body.location
                  },
                  "phone": {
                    "S": req.body.phone
                  },
                  "ccode": {
                    "S": req.body.ccode
                  },
                  "grad": {
                    "S": req.body.grad
                  },
                  "pgrad": {
                    "S": req.body.pgrad
                  },
                  "ograd": {
                    "S": req.body.ograd
                  },
                  "experience": {
                    "N": "10"
                  },
                  "linkedin": {
                    "S": req.body.linkedin
                  },
                  "terms": {
                    "S": tandc
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
```

When i excicute this code i am getting an error like this.

```
ValidationException: A value provided cannot be converted into a number
```

I tried with this.

```
var exps = Number(exp);
```

But still, this error persist what can I do? any idea?

My code is like this.

```
  dynamodb.batchWriteItem(createuser, function(err, regdata) {
    vulog.debug(regdata);
    if (err || !regdata || regdata.Responses.UnprocessedItems) {
      vulog.warn('ddb: error in checking corp user details1 \n' + err);
      res.send(400, 'Unable to register at present, please try later');
      return;
    }
    vulog.debug('Candidate added successful');

    res.send(200, 'Success! Your account has been created.\n Check your email for further instructions.');
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the values must be strings:

for example :

```
"fname": {
    "S": req.body.fname
}
```

> req.body.fname must be a string

so just add

```
req.body.fname + ""
```

OR

> req.body.fname.toString();

Comment: THis is not working i am keep getting this error `ValidationException: A value provided cannot be converted into a number`

Comment: your error is here "userid": { "N": "usrid" } , delete the quotes from the userid. and cast the userid to string :   "userid": { "N": usrid + "" }

Comment: still no hope :(

Comment: But the error is changed `ValidationException: One or more parameter values were invalid: An AttributeValue may not contain an empty string`

Comment: ok, so according to the error, check if you don't have any empty string, can you do console.log(createuser) and show the result

Comment: this is the out put `{ RequestItems: { users: [ [Object] ], candidate: [ [Object] ] } }`

Comment: can you do console.log(JSON.stringify(createuser))

Comment: New json still no hope:(

Comment: `ValidationException: One of the required keys was not given a value`

Comment: can you show your dynamodb keys! check the spelling of your attributes !

Comment: there is no keys this is in local host

Comment: check the spelling of your attributes !

Comment: @ArunVM did you fixed it ?

Comment: Nope :( i am comparing the stuffs

Comment: @ArunVM did you fixed it ?

Comment: Not yet :( I kept this for a while Dynamo db is not that easy any way